# Fast API + PySpark Deployment on Kuberentes

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, fastapi

We are developing a FASTApi Rest project which will get a JSON in POST method and base don the inputs will run a transformation logic using PySpark.

```
def sparkConnection():

      conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PySpark App").setMaster("spark://XX.XXX.XX.XXX:7077).setAll([('spark.executor.cores', '4'),
     ('spark.cores.max', '80'),('spark.app.name','eio_kpi_dashboard'), 
     ('spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled', 'false'),])
     spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
     return spark
```

and then this context is called by the

```
  @network_kpis.post('/top-kpis', status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
  async def topkpisService(request: pydantic.Schema, db : Session = Depends(get_db)):
       results = serviceImpl.getTopKpis(request, DR, VTRC, KFR, db)
       return responseSchema(code=200, status='SUCCESS', message='API executed successfully', 
                             result= results)


  def getTopKpis(request, DR, VTRC, kpi_table, db):

     try:

         jsonbody=jsonable_encoder(request)
         print(jsonbody)
         startDate = jsonbody['startDate'].split(' ')[0]
         spark = utils.sparkConnection()
```

Then we are deploying this FastAPI service using DockerFile over Google Kubernetes cluster

```
   FROM ubuntu:22.04
   RUN apt-get update && \
       apt-get install libpq-dev && \
       apt-get install python3-dev && \
       apt-get -y install python3-pip



  WORKDIR /home/usr/app/
  COPY . .
  RUN pip install -r /home/usr/app/requirements.txt
  CMD ["uvicorn", "controller.main:app",  "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "6098"]
  EXPOSE 6098
```

However when we hit the service we are getting the following error of RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.

Please note the Spark Master is running in a different Pod and FastAPI is running in a different pod.